# CSS Dropdown Menu Shift

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, nav

I'm curious why my 'homepage' link keeps shifting over. I've made a fiddle of the problem:

jsfiddle.net/nbf8fwdv/

Thanks for the help. I'm still getting the hang of semantics and proper usage in CSS, so if you see any glaring problems with my code that only a beginner would make, please let me know. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to prevent the homepage from shifting on hover, you'll want to remove this property:

```
max-width: 75px;
```

from this class:

```
nav ul>li:hover {
        background-color: rgba(253,235,193,.6);
        max-width: 75px;
        text-align:center;
}
```

Because the homepage list item is naturally greater than 75px, the max-width property is actually reducing it's width on hover.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a class like bootstrap

```
body {
    background-color: white;
    font-family: PT Sans, sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(166,166,166,.2);
}
header {
    background: white;
    width: 100%
    padding: 40px 0;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
nav {
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(166,166,166,.2);
}
nav ul {
    background-color: rgba(253,235,193,.3);
    overflow: visible;
    color: white;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}
nav ul>li:hover {
    background-color: rgba(253,235,193,.6);    
    text-align:center;
}
nav ul li:hover ul{
    display: block;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
nav ul li:hover li{
    margin-left: -40px;
    margin-top:-15px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}

.portfolio_menu{position:absolute;top:100%;left:0;z-index:1000;display:none;float:left;min-width:160px;padding:5px 0;margin:2px 0 0;font-size:14px;text-align:left;list-style:none;background-color:#fff;-webkit-background-clip:padding-box;background-clip:padding-box;border:1px solid #ccc;border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);border-radius:4px;-webkit-box-shadow:0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);box-shadow:0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175)}
```

Answer (score 0):

To actually save your other links by shifting over when hover over the "portfolio", here is my 2 cents. http://jsfiddle.net/nbf8fwdv/5/

```
  nav ul ul {
        display: none;
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
    }
```